# Express-throttle how to set cost of api call based on argument for function

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, throttling

I'm using express-throttle to limit the amount of api calls per IP address per day. I want to set the 'cost' parameter in the 'options' array based on a value in the api request. (please see comment 'QUESTION' in the code).

So the parameter in the request determines the cost of the api call with regards to the maximum-per-day-counter (throttle takes care of that). The problem is, that throttle(options) is called as an argument of app.post.. so it's too late to set it?

How should I do that? I'm thinking callback, but am not sure how to implement. I tried to do 2 consecutive api calls, but that can lead to a timing issue. Please advice. Thanks.

Code:

```
var throttle = require("express-throttle");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var options = {
  "burst": 100,
  "period": "1d",

  // "cost" : 3; <<< This needs to be set to a value from the request.

  "on_throttled": function(req, res, next, bucket) {
      // Set responsemessage when maximum has been reached.
    res.status(503).send("Come back tomorrow.");
  }
};

app.get("/throttletest", throttle(options), (req, res, next) => {

    // QUESTION : I need to set the "cost" parameter to res.body.userBurst.

    res.send("Ok Throttletest");

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now trying to set it like this:

```
var options = {
  "burst": 100,
  "period": 1d,
  "cost": function(req){
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    return amount;
  },
```

Have to test first.

Comment: I was going to mention, according to the docs, cost can be a function: https://github.com/GlurG/express-throttle

Comment: Yes. My bad, typical case of over-thinking and under-reading ;) Thanks, Max!